# Object not instance of declaring class on deep dozer mapping with collection

Tags: java, dozer

I'm trying to deep map via dozer the properties of two class which are of type set. my sample code below,

```
class SomeObject {
    String name;
}

class AnotherObject {
    String myName;
}

class A {
    private String identity;
    private Set < SomeObject > someSet  = new HashSet < SomeObject >;
}

class B {
    private String id;
    private Set < AnotherObject > someAnotherSet = new HashSet < AnotherObject >;
}
```

below is following code i tried for for deep mapping via dozer API

```
BeanMappingBuilder builder = new  BeanMappingBuilder () {
    mapping(A.class, B.class)
        .fields("identity", "id")
        .fields("someSet.name", "someAnotherSet.myName");
}
```

On running above example, I ge following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please put more effort into using actual code - the code you've provided is not only not formatted, but it's clearly not real code, with `Class` instead of `class` in the declarations. Please provide a [mcve], and remember that the primary goal of Stack Overflow is to create a repository of high quality questions and answers. You may find https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ helpful when crafting a high quality question.

Comment: What inputs did you provide?